Understanding the question of "Find the 95% confidence interval of 100 coin flips"
I see this question all the time...

Find the 95% confidence interval of 100 coin flips

This is a classic data science or stats interview question. So, I believe you should use methods to find the answer with a back of the envelope method and use the CLT.
But...How do I interpret this question? Do I think of it as asking confidence interval for the number of coin flips or for $\hat{p}$?
For a Bernoulli, the standard error is the same as the mean... for a fair coin:
$$SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{.5(1-.5)}{100}} = 0.05$$
$$CI = \hat{x} \pm 1.96 SE \implies .5 \pm 1.96 \cdot 0.05 \implies (0.402, 0.598)$$
Let's say we want the confidence interval of the number of flips...can we just use a z-score for the number of successes if there is a sufficient number of flips (well writing this out it doesn't seem to be a z-score)?
$$ \mu = n \cdot p \quad \sigma = \sqrt{n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)} \implies z = \frac{n \cdot p}{\sqrt{n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)}} = 10$$
$$CI = (30.4, 69.6)$$
When I simulate this I find answers that matches what I see online... I get:
$$CI = (40, 60)$$
This value is much closer to the confience interval of $p$ but mulitplied by $100$. Can I just multiply the CI of $p$ by $100$?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def bernoulli_ci(n, p =.5, ci=1.96):
  se = (p*(1-p)/n)**.5
  me = ci*se
  return (p - me, p + me)

def binom_ci(n, p =.5, ci=1.96):
    zscore = (n*p)/(n*p*(1-p))**.5
    me = ci*zscore
    return (n*p - me, n*p + me)


S = 100000
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(S, N)))
df = (df > .5).sum(axis=1) # number of heads
print("Bernoulli CI", bernoulli_ci(N))
print("binom CI", binom_ci(N))

alpha = .05
df = df.sort_values()
print("emperical ci", (df.quantile(alpha/2), df.quantile(1-alpha/2)))


The target of a confidence interval is, by definition, a property of the model (of the coin, in this case). Neither the number of flips nor the estimate $\hat p$ are such properties.  This suggests you would get a lot out of reviewing the definitions and concepts: look, for instance, at the top hits in this site search for posts on confidence intervals.

You're first two sentences are a bit unclear to me. can you please elaborate?

They are fully explained in the top hits of that search I linked to.

If $X$ is the number of heads from $100$ flips of a fair coin then, using the binomial distribution $Bin(100,\frac12)$, you get $P(40 \le X \le 60)\approx 0.965$ and $P(40 \lt X \lt 60)\approx 0.943$. So that is presumably the interpretation of the $[40,60]$ interval, though I would not call it a "confidence interval".
$E[X]=50$ and $Var(X)=25=5^2$, so if you were using a normal approximation aiming for a $95\%$ interval, you would get about  $50\pm1.96\times 5$ as the ends of the interval, i.e. about $40.2$ and $59.8$.  This is close to the exact binomial distribution.
One of your calculations divides all this by $n=100$ to suggest $[0.402,0.598]$.  This might be your (Wald) confidence interval for the probability of Heads from a possibly unfair coin where the observation was $50$ Heads from $100$ flips.
Your other $(30.4,69.6)$ numbers seem to have come implicitly from $z=\frac\mu\sigma$ but this is not a $z$-score in the usual sense. This is not a meaningful approach.

why is it times $1.96 \times 5$? Where is the $5$ coming from? Why are you using probability range for the first part?

@user2330624: $5=\sqrt{25}$ is the standard deviation.  You wrote $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ and here $n=100$ while a fair coin has $p=\frac12$.

Why is it not $1.96 \cdot \frac{\mu}{\sigma}$ for a zscore? ah.... I think I got confused. you'd compare the zscore to 1.96 rather than use it in a CI.  Okay but why for the Bernoulli do we not use the raw standard deviation like we do for a binomial?

Why do we use the definition of standard error for binomial but we use definition of SE for $p$ CI?

The so-called $z$-score is usually $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ or, when applied to sample averages, $\frac{\bar X- \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}$
